# Windows Service Install

Tags: wcf, windows-services, installation

I have a WCF Host with an Installer. What I'd like to achieve is to be able to communicate with another WCF service already installed as Windows Service on some machine.

Is this possible ? Maybe if I override the Install method of the installer? Is this recommended?

Do you guys see another way of achieving this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you asking if it's possible for two WCF services to communicate with one another?  Are you asking about how to install a WCF service?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. My question is during the installation of a wcf service through an MSI. I want to communicate with another wcf already installed on some machine. 

So I was asking if this was possible. I did found a way by overriding the Install of the Installer class but not sure its the correct way.

Comment: Oh, so you want to communicate with a Windows service that is hosting a WCF service during the installation of another WCF service?  I would think override the installer would be the way to do this, but it's not something I've ever done.  What happens if the Windows service isn't there (or is there but isn't running)?

Comment: It's exactly it. If the service isn't there, it shouldn't install. The problem I'm having is, it seems that I can't access the app.config file when I'm runing the MSI ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do at install time?  Your idea of overriding the install method of the installer class sounds like the right idea to me.